# VBA if statement to be shortened

Tags: vba, loops, if-statement

how can i shorten my if statement? is there any other way to shorten it??

```
F = Strt
E = Strt + A1
I = Strt + A1 + A2
A = Strt + A2 + A1 + A3
b = Strt + A2 + A1 + A3 + A4
c = Strt + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5
D = Strt + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6
G = Strt + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7
H = Strt + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7 + A8
J = Strt + A1 + A2 + A3 + A4 + A5 + A6 + A7 + A8 + A9


    If F >= Row Then
    asd = 0
    ElseIf E >= Row Then
    asd = 1
    ElseIf I >= Row Then
    asd = 2
    ElseIf A >= Row Then
    asd = 3
    ElseIf b >= Row Then
    asd = 4
    ElseIf c >= Row Then
    asd = 5
    ElseIf D >= Row Then
    asd = 6
    ElseIf G >= Row Then
    asd = 7
    ElseIf H >= Row Then
    asd = 8
    ElseIf J >= Row Then
    asd = 9
    Else
    End If
```

and also my variables.. i wonder if i can shorten it..
very much appreciated if answerd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been years since I've done vba, but here's the pseudo-code for how I would solve it:

```
arr = [Strt+A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, A8, A9]
for i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ // assume 0-based array
    if i > 0
        arr[i] = arr[i-1]+arr[i] // sum
    if Row <= arr[i]
        asd = i
        break
```

This should do exactly what your code is doing, just more simply. Basically, you're summing A1-A9 (starting from Strt), and returning the index where Strt is <= (Strt + sum(A1..Ai)).

I find this code more readable, and it's definitely shorter and easier to extend later.

Comment: Sir.. the code is executing what i need.. im so sorry i forgot to include my function line.. here is the line Function asd(A1 As Integer, A2 As Integer, A3 As Integer, A4 As Integer, A5 As Integer, A6 As Integer, Strt As Integer, Row As Integer) now is there any way? im using vba in excel.. the variables A1...A6 used in the cell that contains =asd($E$4,$I$4,$M$4,$Q$4,$U$4,$Y$4,$AC$4,AL3).. is there any other way?? my apologies

Comment: @AllenTheGreat - What about my pseudo-code isn't correct or simpler than what you have? All you need to do is change my pseudo-code to be syntactically correct and you have a 7 line function vs a 33 line function.

Comment: ok ill try ill update you if some errors occur... thanks BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Option Explicit
Function ASD(byval F as Range, byval E as Range, byval I as Range, _
byval A as Range, byval Row as Range) As Integer

Dim var
Dim ctr As Integer
Dim data As Variant

ctr = 0
data = Array(F.Value, E.Value, I.Value, A.Value)
For Each var In data
    If var >= Row.Value Then
       ASD = ctr
       Exit Function
    End If

    ctr = ctr + 1
Next
ASD = -1
End Function
```

Comment: Sir.. the code is executing what i need.. im so sorry i forgot to include my function line.. here is the line
    Function asd(A1 As Integer, A2 As Integer, A3 As Integer, A4 As Integer, A5 As Integer, A6 As Integer, Strt As Integer, Row As Integer)
now is there any way? im using vba in excel.. the variables A1...A6 used in the cell that contains =asd($E$4,$I$4,$M$4,$Q$4,$U$4,$Y$4,$AC$4,AL3)..
is there any other way?? my apologies

Comment: @AllenTheGreat: See if the modified version helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested the code but should work with little modification, if required

```
For i = 0 To 9
    If Str >= Row then
        asd = i 
        Exit for
    End If
    Str = Str + INDIRECT("A" + i + 1) 'assuming A1, A2 etc are cell addresses .. 
Next i
```

Comment: Sir.. the code is executing what i need.. im so sorry i forgot to include my function line.. here is the line Function asd(A1 As Integer, A2 As Integer, A3 As Integer, A4 As Integer, A5 As Integer, A6 As Integer, Strt As Integer, Row As Integer) now is there any way? im using vba in excel.. the variables A1...A6 used in the cell that contains =asd($E$4,$I$4,$M$4,$Q$4,$U$4,$Y$4,$AC$4,AL3).. is there any other way?? my apologies